# How to replace all but specific part of string in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a list with lines like this:

> 103238704-|--|-INEEDTHIS-|-r4Vp5iL2VbM=-|-maiden  name|--

Is there a way in Notepad++ to delete everything except `INEEDTHIS`?

`INEEDTHIS` will be an email address.

Comment: Just use search and replace option.
Search with 103238704-|--|-INEEDTHIS-|-r4Vp5iL2VbM=-|-maiden name|-- and replace with INEEDTHIS.

Comment: Yea well, but every line is different for example the next line looks like this
103238705-|--|-othertext-|-BB4e6X+b2xLioxG6CatHBw==-|-boyfriend|--

Comment: -1 DEFINE WHAT ON EARTH THAT  PART IN THE MIDDLE CAN LOOK LIKE, Barbar in comment gave you a perfectly good answer(given what you asked) in comment (replace the entire thing with INEEDTHIS) then you said the middle can be |-othertext-|  You get a well deserved -1 for that. You should write your question better.

Answer (score 0):

Then you can try Regex like this:

```
[0-9]{9}\-\|\-\-\|\-(\w+)\-\|\-.+\|\-[\w\ ]+\|\-\-
```

This match both string.
You will have to replace with `$1`, which will be the value you want.
Could not test on Notepad++, as I don't have it.
But tested on my Editor, PhpStrom.

Update:
To also match email addresses, better use this:

```
[0-9]{9}\-\|\-\-\|\-([\w\@\.]+)\-\|\-.+\|\-[\w\ ]+\|\-\-
```

Comment: Wouldn't that remove all the numbers ? Because unfortunately "INEEDTHIS" has digits sometimes ;[

Comment: No it will match letters and digits. a-z, A-Z, 0-9

Comment: My lines are like this
103251697-|--|-euniceknx@hotmail.com-|-ZI88rWBSuQPioxG6CatHBw==-|-twilight|--
It would work if it wasn't for the hotmail :F

And btw not all are at hotmail

Comment: `[0-9]{9}\-\|\-\-\|\-([\w\@\.]+)\-\|\-.+\|\-[\w\ ]+\|\-\-`
This match all three lines and filter the required part, including hotmail address!

Comment: Just use `(.*?)` and be done with it.

Comment: Thank you so much Babar! How can I give you rep or something :D?
hmm it actually cleared most of them, but there are some left for example 
103238923-|--|-y-tomoko@nifty.com-|-/lC7pSicTTk=-|-???|--
103238922-|--|-ndenler@hotmail.com-|-78oCcp+nW7/ioxG6CatHBw==-|-|--

Comment: @Lottex it's really not clear what the middle can be, you haven't defined it so how is anybody supposed to know.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
^(.*?)-\|-(.*?)-\|-(.*?)-\|-.*$
```

Replace with

```
$3
```

This makes no assumptions about the content of submatches between the `-|-` separators.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:[^|]+\|-){2}([^|]+)-.+$
```

This should work just fine as long as your delimiter won't change.

1. `^`: let's start at the beginning
2. `(?:[^|]+\|-)`: matches everything that's not a pipe symbol, a pipe symbol and a following hyphen (because of `?:` this is a non-capturing group)
3. `{2}`: exactly 2 times
4. `([^|]+)`: this is your captured match; matches everything that's not a pipe symbol
5. `-.+$`: matches a dash and every character until the end of the line

Works with every samply you provided:

> 103238704-|--|-INEEDTHIS-|-r4Vp5iL2VbM=-|-maiden name|--
>   103238705-|--|-othertext-|-BB4e6X+b2xLioxG6CatHBw==-|-boyfriend|--
>   103251697-|--|-euniceknx@hotmail.com-|-ZI88rWBSuQPioxG6CatHBw==-|-twilight|--
>   103238923-|--|-y-tomoko@nifty.com-|-/lC7pSicTTk=-|-???|-- 
>   103238922-|--|-ndenler@hotmail.com-|-78oCcp+nW7/ioxG6CatHBw==-|-|--